# Pytest assert of returned value from method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

This is works as expected:

```
def my_method():
    return True;

def test_method():
    assert my_method()
```

But this not:

```
assert filecmp.cmp(path1, path2)
```

Instead I get:

```
AssertionError: assert <function cmp at 0x1042db840>((((('/Users/vital...my-path
```

Of course I can assign result (`True` or `False` from `filecmp.cmp()`) to variable and `assert` this variable, but why `assert` works for first method but not for second? And maybe is there a way to `assert` from `filecmp.cmp()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems right. This looks like the regular py.test output if an `assert` was not fulfilled.

Are `path1` and `path2` really equal? Try

```
assert filecmp.cmp(path1, path1)
```

to see if the `assert` statement itself works.